# Encrypt sharepoint online list columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, permissions, security

I'm somewhat proficient in development but have basic knowledge about SharePoint and Sharepoint Online.

I would like to **add an encryption thing** to my Sharepoint Online list columns make it

- possible to select if it should be
- private (only the creator should be able to see the decrypted value)
- role-based (only people with a certain role should be able to see the decrypted value)
- public (everybody can see the decrypted value).

I understand I need some kind of customization to do this, so my question is:

1. Whats the best practice for encrypting list columns? Any built in API functions I can use?
2. Is it even possible to add customization to SharePoint Online? Please guide me where to start?

Comment: Do you need the data encrypted or just hidden? And should it be encrypted on the DB side or just on the web side? From above sounds more like you just need information hidden to certain people which can be handled by permissions

Comment: Need encryption in database, don't want to encrypt the entire database, just some list columns. Data needs to be protected as it's sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-field-permissions/overview/) 3rd party  add-on and this [Laura Rogers Blog](https://wonderlaura.com/2015/02/04/mimicking-column-security/).

Also check these simple solutions in [this blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-office-365-column-level-security-iss/).
**1. Create Target Audiences.**

**2. Using Password column as Look Up column :**
Use Password column as a Look up column from another new list . In our project we are using this approach.

Following are the steps:

- Consider our main list which has Server details and in this list we need to implement column level security for Password column - call this list as ListA
- Create a separate list for the values of Password column. Add the Password column in the list which we want to make secure - call this list as ListB (Lookup list)
- Add all the possible values of Password column as list items in ListB
- Break the inheritance of ListB
- Give the permissions to only users who we want to see the Password column values in ListA
- Add the above column as a look up column to our main list ListA
- Now when user will visit the main list ListA only users who has the permissions to the look up list ListB, only those users can see the values of look up column in ListA.

Comment: Thank you Asim but this has no encryption, it's only about who can see what? I guess it'll help me a part of the way but I need encryption in the database and decryption + view permissions on the client side based on roles/users.

Comment: what is "Password column" ?